# How do you output a process time-span in power shell

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to output how long a process was running for before it was closed. I was trying to experiment with `Where_Object {$_.}` but nothing related with time outputs how long the process was running. I was looking at CPU(s) -*The amount of processor time that the process has used on all processors, in seconds.* I thought this would solve my problem but it doesn't output how long the application was running for. An example of what I'm trying to accomplish would be "If you wanted to know how many seconds you were using Google Chrome today." Here's what I have tried.

```
 $getchrometime = Get-Process -name chrome| Where-Object {$_.CPU}
    Write-output $getchrometime| Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Also when I use Format-Table -AutoSize in the ISE the table is not set above it's value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEp9Y.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `starttime` of all `chrome.exe` processes(There may be many)

```
$chrome = Get-Process -Name chrome | select -ExpandProperty starttime
```

calculate the running time by subtracting the `starttime` from the `currenttime`.

```
$chrome | New-TimeSpan | Select -Expand TotalSeconds
```

#### here is a variation that is slightly better

```
$Chrome = Get-Process -Name chrome
$Chrome |  
    ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name RunningTime -Value (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds

   }

$Chrome | Select-Object Name,ID,RunningTime
```

Comment: Thank you for the response; how can I convert it into seconds, so it displays the amount of seconds the app was running for before I closed it, with the `close` button. So for example I open chrome for 40 seconds and then close it. How would I output those seconds that it was open for.

Comment: Obviously if a process isnt running there is no way to get its starttime or any of its other properties so you may want to setup some process counters (procmon) to run every 10 seconds or whatever interval suits you